# How can I generate hash codes with Scala

Tags: scala, hash

I want to generate a non cryptographic hash code for a string in Scala 2.11

I looked online and found a class called MurmurHash3 but when I try to use it I get a very unhelpful `class MurmurHash3 in package hashing cannot be accessed in package scala.util.hashing`

Why would I not be able to access the package? Is there an alternative?

Comment: what's wrong with `java.security.MessageDigest`?

Comment: Never heard of that before but I found that even `myString.hashCode()` suffices. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the class MurmurHash3 is private

```
private[hashing] class MurmurHash3
```

what you need, is a companion object MurmurHash3. Don't try to instantiate it. Just use it's methods, like in a static class

```
util.hashing.MurmurHash3.stringHash("")
```

Answer (score 1):

public instace of `MurmurHash3` is **object** not a **class**:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_65)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3.arrayHash(Array(10,20,30))
res0: Int = -864874452
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try java's `security.MessageDigest` to generate hash code in scala. It will generate same hash code for same input string. I used this in Scala 2.11.x

```
import java.security.MessageDigest

def getMD5Hash(fileName: String): String = {
    val msgDigest:MessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
    val MD5Hash = msgDigest.digest(fileName.getBytes()).map(0xFF & _).map { "%02x".format(_) }.foldLeft("") {_ + _}
    MD5Hash
}
```

Hope it Helps!